# Google picker does not work without filter being applied for some users

Tags: google-picker

we have an integrated with google picker(read-only scope,Docs view) it use to work fine but recently some users are getting blank screens as soon as the pop up shows but when they select some filter everything starts working fine after that no problems.

using developer tools i see all apis returning 200 for that first request
but there were no docs in response(i believe this is the api responsible for bringing docs in picker 'https://docs.google.com/picker/pvr')

when there are no docs returned in above api google is calling another api i assume it is to log error's probably(//docs.google.com/picker/ohnoes)
this api has following error params in it

```
&error=Cached and requested query mismatch
&line=Not available
&viewToken=["all",null,{"query":null}]
&ms=97
&transferDocs=false
&numErrors=1
```

has anybody else faced the similar problem
what do error "Cached and requested query mismatch" means in context of drive docs

Fyi - most accounts facing this problem seems like are of company domain for ex "jondoe@company.org"(this is a google account with company domain)

[Filters Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSfGw.png)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: what are these filters you're reffering to?

Comment: attached available filters image to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure but looks like issue was may be related to google bug 
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64825685

for me the code that was not working was:

```
 addView(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS)
```

replaced this code with below code which works as expected

```
var view = new google.picker.DocsView();
        view.setIncludeFolders(true).setOwnedByMe(true).setParent('root');

addView(view).
```